# How to solve this set Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a survey it was found that the ratio of people who liked arithmetic and algebra is $\frac98$.

If $25\%$ like both, $80$ liked none of these and $20\%$ liked arithmetic only, find the total number of people participated in the survey.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please share your efforts in solving this problem

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: Make a venn diagram, it is always the best way to do these type of sums, also your question is about sets, so tag it with sets. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r,b,g,n$ be the number of people who likes a**r**ithmetic only, **b**oth arithmetic and algebra, al**g**ebra only, and **n**either of the subjects, then we have:

$$\begin{cases}
r+b &= 9/8 \times (g+b)\\
b &= 0.25 \times (r+b+g+n)\\
n &= 80\\
r &= 0.2 \times (r+b+g+n)
\end{cases}$$

I am sure you can solve this system.

Comment: ans should be 200 but when calculated as above it comes 91.71=92

Comment: And i think y+z=0.2x+only(algebra)+0.25x

Comment: Sorry DeepSea i understand logic but couldnot solve even though  know it value will come as 4 variable 4 equation.

Comment: b = 50,   m = 40,   n = 30,   p = 80-thanks i got ans which is as given (50+40+30+80)=200